# Let $\frac1{1+x^2}+\frac1{1+y^2}=\frac2{1+xy}$. Find $\left(x+\frac1y\right)\left(y+\frac1x\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $x,y \in \mathbb R$, $x \not =y$ and satisfy
> $$\frac1{1+x^2}+\frac1{1+y^2}=\frac2{1+xy}$$
> Find
> $$\left(x+\frac1y\right)\left(y+\frac1x\right)$$

#### My work so far:

$$\left(x+\frac1y\right)\left(y+\frac1x\right)=\frac{(xy+1)^2}{xy}$$
$$\frac{x^2 + y^2 + 2}{(x^2 + 1) (y^2 + 1)} = \frac2{x y + 1}$$

Comment: Are your two lines of work related?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints**: observe
$$
(x^2+y^2+2)(xy+1)-2(x^2+1)(y^2+1)=(x-y)^2(xy-1)
$$
and recall that the problem gives $x\neq y$. Next, note that
$$
\Big(x+\frac{1}{y}\Big)\Big(y+\frac{1}{x}\Big)
$$
only depends on $x$ and $y$ via $xy$.